# Choose payment method for mini app

Tags: google-app-engine, payment, paypal

I'm starting developing a mini e-commerce system for mobile, and I'm stack with the two options paypal offer:
method 1: Using API Credentials for seller (express checkout api)

method 2: Seller use only email (send money api)

Does any one know what should I consider while choosing the methods listed above ?

Comment: I am not aware of an API for your method 2. What do you mean by "send money api"? Can you point me to the docs for that?

Comment: In method 2, seller only use email for payment. 
Such as: http://checkthis.com/ (in SELL option). When you sell something, you can choose title, image, price, payment... At payment section (processed by Paypal), you only provide email. 
And I think, they use "Sending money with paypal" method (https://www.paypal-marketing.co.uk/sendmoney/index.htm) in this case.
Can you help me know the difference about 2 methods technical!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of e-commerce system you are planning to make.

If you are creating an online store system, like Amazon.com, then the Express Checkout API would be a good choice.

But if you are creating a system that connects buyers and sellers, like ebay.com, then you could go ahead with your second method. Though Paypal lets you accept payments via email, I'm not aware of an API for that. If you want to proceed with this method, you'd have to create your own workarounds or find a workaround that someone else published.

Comment: Thank you for answer! It's true, my app is connect buyer and seller. Seller can add many things to sell (not only one). But I still don't know why should I choose second method? (aspects of technology)

Comment: I think most of the sites I've seen that connects buyer and seller, uses your method 1 to receive payment from the buyer. It goes something like this. The seller lists what they are selling on your system, and the buyer pays you (through method 1). You pay the seller using your method 2, and ask the seller to deliver the product. The problem with this is that paypal also takes a cut from every transaction. You'd have to design your system in a way that provides the most value for you, and more importantly, your users.